# How would I go about merging two text files into a new text file?

Tags: c++

I have two text files. First one looks like this.

```
00000000000000000000000000000000





11100000000000000000000000000000
00010000000000000000000000000000
10100000000000000000000000000000
10100000000000000000000000000000
```

(the empty spaces in this file are a ' ' space character)

and the other one looks like this

```
11100000000000000000000000000000
00010000000000000000000000000000
10100000000000000000000000000000
10100000000000000000000000000000
00010000000000000000000000000000
```

i'd like to insert or replace the empty lines in the first text file with the second text file

Comment: Okay so go ahead and do that. Have fun!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The algorithm is pretty straightforward - it follows the general approach to two-way merging that you see in all algorithms:

- Open both input files, and the output file, as streams
- Read lines from the first file one-by-one
- If the line that you read is non-empty, copy it into the output
- Otherwise, read the next line from the second file, and copy it into the output
- Once the first file is exhausted, copy the rest of the second file into the output.

Comment: cheers it was really simple I think I was just overcomplicating it in my head